# Displaying multiple screen in a picturebox c#

Tags: c#

Im quite new at c# and i've  been searching and searching for an answer on my stupid problem and I cant seem to find it. Here it goes:

I'm creating a simple snipping tool program that I want to capture all monitor screens connected. When I start the program I have 2 monitors running. But the picturebox shows both screens only on one screen

[image: See picture]

How do I solve this so they appear as snipping tool does?

The code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActiveForm.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CheckEscKeyPress);
    //Hide the Form
    this.Hide();
    int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
    int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
    int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
    int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(screenWidth, screenHeight);

    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(screenLeft, screenTop);
    //Create the Bitmap
    //Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
    //                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width,
           SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height,
           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    //Create the Graphic Variable with screen Dimensions
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
    //Copy Image from the screen
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //save graphic variable into memory
        printscreen.Save(s, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

        pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);
        //set the picture box with temporary stream
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(s);
    }

    //this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(screenLeft, screenTop);
    //this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.Show();
    //Cross Cursor
    Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some clarification on your issue, your wording is ambiguous.

Comment: as @JamesHughes said, please specify and describe your problem clearly, and what does not work as excepted.. currently the issue is not understandable

Comment: Put multiple pictureboxes into a panel control. One picturebox for each image.

Comment: A hard limitation in winforms is that you cannot make a window larger than the screen on which it is displayed.  So since the form cannot be large enough, inevitably your picturebox can't be large enough either to cover both screens.  Using 2 forms would be a workaround.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want to make a snipping tool like app but the problem i face is that if i have 2 screens and start the copyfromscreen method to copy the displays and put them in one picture box, the picture box does not strech itself and only pops up on one screen. Could be what hans wrote. Winforms aint that smart. Hope its abit more clear now